# Custom row listview adapter crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-custom-view

I tried following [slidenerds youtube 6 part tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zQCv0Xb3pk) to create a listview with custom rows.  In his tutorial he uses 1 image and 2 textviews, I needed 3 images and 3 textviews, when I run the app it crashes trying to load up the listview.

-------------homesinglerow.xml-----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lilly"
    android:textColor="#2c7134"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/dogName"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dogimage"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="sendProfile"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/lilly"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timestamp 1"
            android:textColor="#2c7134"
            android:id="@+id/timestamp1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dog1num1"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="75dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="NumberOne"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/num1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Timestamp 1"
            android:textColor="#2c7134"
            android:id="@+id/timestamp2"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dog1num2"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="75dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="NumberOne"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/num2"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

------------------Homelistview.xml-----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivityListview
"
android:background="@drawable/screenbackground">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selectprofiletext"
    android:textColor="#2c7134"
    android:text="Select a profile or make a post:"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:entries="@array/dogs"
    android:layout_below="@id/selectprofiletext"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newdogbutton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add new dog"
    android:id="@+id/newdogbutton"
    android:background="#2c7134"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:textColor="#f3ca83"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="AddNewDog"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

----------------Homeactivitylistview.java-----------------------

```
public class HomeActivityListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    Context context;
    ArrayList dogName;
    ArrayList dogID;
    int [] dogImages = {R.drawable.lilly, R.drawable.dogpic};
    public static int [] dogNames={R.id.dogName, R.id.dogName};
    int [] num1={R.id.dog1num1, R.id.dog1num1, R.id.dog1num1, R.id.dog1num1, R.id.dog1num1};
    int [] num2={R.id.dog1num2, R.id.dog1num2, R.id.dog1num2, R.id.dog1num2, R.id.dog1num2};
    String[] names;
    String[] timestamp1;
    String[] timestamp2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_activity_listview);

        Resources res = getResources();
        names=res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
        timestamp1=res.getStringArray(R.array.timestamps1);
        timestamp2=res.getStringArray(R.array.timestamps2);
        context=this;

        list =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        dogAdapter adapter=new dogAdapter(this, names, dogImages, num1, num2, timestamp1, timestamp2);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

class dogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    int[] dogImages;
    int[] num1;
    int[] num2;
    String[] nameArray;
    String[] timestamp1Array;
    String[] timestamp2Array;
    dogAdapter(Context c, String[] names, int imgs[], int numb1[], int numb2[], String[] time1, String[] time2)
    {
        super(c,R.layout.home_single_row,R.id.dogName,names);
        this.context=c;
        this.dogImages=imgs;
        this.num1=numb1;
        this.num2=numb2;
        this.nameArray=names;
        this.timestamp1Array=time1;
        this.timestamp2Array=time2;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_single_row,parent, false);

        ImageView dogImg=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.dogimage);
        ImageView img1=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.dog1num1);
        ImageView img2=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.dog1num2);
        TextView name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dogName);
        TextView time1=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.timestamp1);
        TextView time2=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.timestamp2);

        dogImg.setImageResource(dogImages[position]);
        img1.setImageResource(dogImages[position]);
        img2.setImageResource(dogImages[position]);
        name.setText(nameArray[position]);
        time1.setText(timestamp1Array[position]);
        time2.setText(timestamp2Array[position]);

        return row;
    }
}



public void sendProfile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DogProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void NumberOne(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number one");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }
    public void NumberTwo(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDlg.setMessage("Confirm Dog went number two");
        alertDlg.setCancelable(false);

        alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        alertDlg.setNegativeButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        alertDlg.create().show();

    }

    public void AddNewDog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewDogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

04-22 15:49:36.597 28628-28628/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid, PID: 28628
                                                                                java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 738608 free bytes and 721KB until OOM
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:157)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:85)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:81)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:59)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:55)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                    at cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivityListview$dogAdapter.getView(HomeActivityListview.java:74)
                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.o

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
 list.setAdapter(dogAdapter);
```

> **[setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter))** Sets the data behind this ListView. The adapter passed to this method may be wrapped by a WrapperListAdapter,
>   depending on the ListView features currently in use. For instance,
>   adding headers and/or footers will cause the adapter to be wrapped.

I think this important point was not explained in the video!

```
//Get ListView reference.
list =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
//create the Adapter instance.
dogAdapter adapter=new dogAdapter(this, names, dogImages, num1, num2, timestamp1, timestamp2);
//Set the adapter to the ListView!
list.setAdapter(dogAdapter);
```

Comment: It was asking for an expression inside instead of dogAdapter I changed it to adapter and its happy.  Thanks over looked that small step checked back in video he did it fast then clicked away instantly.